# как переопределить контроллер сторонней библиотеки для laravel?

Tags: laravel

есть библиотека которая находится в корне сайта:

```
App
config
...
Biblioteka/Http/Controllers/SettingsController.php
```

контроллер создал нужно просто в него направить чтобы сначала считывалось с моего файла или вообще заменить на мой

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Biblioteka/Http/Controllers/SettingsController.php as BibliotekaSettingsController;

class SettingsController extends BibliotekaSettingsController
{
}
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сталкивался с чем-то похожим в Lumen. Не переопределением контроллера, а переопределение класса вообще. Делал это через composer

```
"autoload": {
    ....
    "exclude-from-classmap":[
        "vendor/vendorname/vendorpackage/src/Namespace/Class.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "PackageName\\": "app/Overrides/PackageName"
    }
},
```

Как-то так. Не уверен что это лучший способ решения проблемы, но для меня он оказался рабочим на все 100%. Так что, как вариант.
Вот еще ссылка с обсуждением этого способа [ссылка на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104574/strategy-to-override-a-class-in-a-library-installed-with-composer)

Answer (score 0):

Само по себе переопределение методов контроллера сторонней библиотеки выглядит сомнительной идеей. Возможно проще реализовать необходимый функционал в методе своего контроллера, чтобы быть уверенном, что ничего не поломается в случае обновления сторонней библиотеки.

Если все же решили так поступить, в принципе одно из решений это унаследоваться от необходимого контроллера, переписать необходимые методы. А затем переписать маршруты в `/routes/web.php` на использование вашего контроллера.

Получить список доступных маршрутов и обрабатывающих их контроллеров можно командой `php artisan route:list`